# How is StartNofity invoked in Python BLE implementation?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus

Environment: Ubuntu 20.04, Python

My BLE gatt server implementation is roughly based on the example here - https://github.com/Douglas6/cputemp.

Here is my relevant code:

```
class RxCharacteristic(Characteristic):
   def __init__(self, service):
      self.notifying = False
      Characteristic.__init__(self, RXCHARID,
                            ['read', 'notify'], service)

   def ReadValue(self, options):
      value = []
      return value

   def StartNotify(self):
      if self.notifying:
        return
      print('Notifying...')
      self.notifying = True
```

When a BLE characteristic is published with "notify" attribute, my understanding is that StartNotify/StopNotify methods are automatically invoked. I guess this happens when the client connects/disconnects.

In my case, when I test my connectivity from "nRF Connect" Android app, I don't see StartNotify getting called.

I am wondering what triggers calling of StartNotify/StopNotify methods. Why am I not seeing it being called? Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable notification in the nRF Connect app. It is the multiple down arrows in the app that does this:

[image]

The Bluetooth daemon will then call the [StartNotify](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt#n181) D-Bus method which in the linked example means [this](https://github.com/Douglas6/cputemp/blob/d6f734b4e2f3ed3b621d9240963da7d169e592a1/service.py#L223) and [this](https://github.com/Douglas6/cputemp/blob/d6f734b4e2f3ed3b621d9240963da7d169e592a1/cputemp.py#L89).

You can monitor the D-Bus calls with:

`sudo busctl monitor org.bluez`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. For some reason, the buttons in nRF Connect app appear and disappear very quickly, even before I get to click on them.